# Where did Interpolation Modes go in Grease Pencil Blender 3.1?

Tags: grease-pencil, interpolation

Just upgraded to Blender 3.1 and cannot for the life of me find the different interpolation modes in Grease Pencil mode. There used to be an options menu with different interpolation modes (sinusoidal, linear, quadratic, etc.) but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: As far as I can tell you have to go to the Grease Pencil view of the Dope Sheet, hover over the dope sheet part of the display and use the T key to bring up the menu.

Comment: don't remember that menu, but after doing ctrl+shift+E you can change the mode in the last action pop-up (bottom left of the viewport), and then it'll use that by default

Comment: Both of these methods work. I ended up rolling back to 2.91 as I know where the menu is. I'm hopeful they'll bring the dialogue back.